# Print character using linux x86 assembly and at&t syntax

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att

I'm trying to print a character to stdout using write in Linux x86 assembly, using at&t syntax. This code doesn’t work:

```
.data

.text

.global main

main:
    movl    $4,%eax
    movl    $1,%ebx
    movl    $53,%ecx //'5'
    movl    $4,%edx
    int     $0x80

    movl    $1,%eax
    movl    $0,%ebx
    int     $0x80
```

What's the problem?

Comment: [`man 2 write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) ... it expects a pointer to the thing to print, so you have to place it into memory, you can't just do `movl $'5', %ecx`.

Comment: I've placed `p: .long  53` and `movl     $p,%ecx` and it works. Thanks

Comment: @Jester: Please make your comment an answer